# Performance of for-loop with high number of cases

Tags: r, performance, loops, for-loop, random

I have 88.000 observations, coded with 1:

```
obs <- rep(1,88000)
```

In addition, I have the following function in which a random experiment is performed. A value p is compared with a random number; depending on the result, x changes (+ 1) or stays the same.

```
rexp <- function(x,p){
  if(runif(1) <= p) return(x + 1)
  return(x)
}
```

Beside "obs" and "rexp" an empty dataframe "dat" with 500 rows and 0 columns is given. There is also a placeholder "result":

```
dat <- data.frame(row.names = 1:500)
dat$result <- rep(',',500)
```

I use following loop to apply the function "rexp" (with p = 0.03) 500 times to the vector "obs" and save the number of changes of "obs" caused by the random experiment as "result" in the dataframe "dat":

```
for(i in 1:500){
  x <- sapply(obs,rexp,0.03)
  x <- table(x)
  x <- x[names(x) == 2]
  dat$result[i] <- x
}
```

Now to the problem: The for-Loop above basically works, but its performance is very bad. The execution takes very long and often the loop even gets stuck. In the example above, there are only 88.000 observations used, working with like 880.000 seems almost impossible. I'm not sure why the performance is so poor. For example, on my device the same procedure is possible in less than a minute in stata  (even with 880.000 observations). I know that for-loops should be bypassed in r anyway, but I do not know how to perform the procedure otherwise. I would be grateful for any hint to explain and improve the performance of the described loop!

Comment: first step would be to replace your `sapply` (loop) with a vectorized version of `rexp`, i.e. `rexp <- function(x, p) {ifelse(runif(length(x)) <= p, x + 1, x)}`. Also `dat` could be initialised as a named vector of integers it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I would do it: first, use a vectorized version of `rexp`, then don't use table if you want to count only the numbers of `2` and don't use characters where you can use integers.

```
rexp <- function(x, p) {
  x + (runif(length(x)) <= p)
}

replicate(500, {
  sum(rexp(obs, 0.03) == 2)
})
```

For an input of size `880`:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  ME = {
    replicate(500, {
      sum(rexp(obs, 0.03) == 2)
    })
  },
  OP = {
    for(i in 1:500){
      x <- sapply(obs,rexp,0.03)
      x <- table(x)
      x <- x[names(x) == 2]
      dat$result[i] <- x
    }
  },
  times = 10
)

Unit: milliseconds
 expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
   ME   18.24666   18.31957   19.64568   20.05481   20.48095   21.69269    10
   OP 1362.54543 1395.50414 1426.17977 1414.25281 1439.75136 1542.97861    10
```